# How to install Laravel with older versions of MariaDB and MySQL? (Exception when you run a migration)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-migrations

**Problem**
From the first try, when I tried to run my first `migrate`, things are already very bad. Why? Because I immediately start with an error message that I've never seen because I was'nt familiar with Laravel (or other frameworks). The error message looks like this examples below:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique users_email_unique(email))
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

When I first saw these exceptions, I've expected that I've ruined the whole application.

How can I solve this problem and workaround (or solve) this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question**
This question is about Laravel and why it is so difficult to install it on a webserver with MariaDB (lower than 10.2.2) or MySQL (lower than 5.7.7). You maybe can't even run the first migration.

**Cause**
Laravel uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. 
(copied word for word from the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations))

**Solution**
At first, the errors/exceptions looks like that your MySQL/MariaDB database is not supported by the application. Do I need to change something? Do I need to configure stuff?

The solution is easy. According to the Laravel documentation, mentioned in the 'Cause', you need to specify your `defaultStringLength`, that is managed by a `Schema`.

You need to edit a file in your Laravel installation that is located at `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

The default page looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You only need to change two rules.

1. In the `usings` you need to add the `Schema`
   `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`
2. You need to specify the `defaultStringLength` in the boot method
   `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

After the changes the code should looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This will tell your migrations how to handle the `defaultStringLength` and what to do with it. After this additions you should be able to run your first `php artisan migrate` and start building awesome stuff!